# Android add items to arraylist using custom class

Tags: android, listview, arraylist

I'm trying to add items to an arraylist using this class template:

```
public class Template {
public String username;
public String email;
```

}

Here's the whole code:

```
public void JsonToArrayList(JSONArray myJsonArray) throws JSONException
{
    ArrayList<Template> listItems = new ArrayList<Template>();
    JSONObject jo = new JSONObject();
    Template tem = new Template();
    ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    for(int i = 0; i<myJsonArray.length(); i++)
    {
        jo = myJsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
        tem.username = jo.getString("username");
        tem.email = jo.getString("user_email");

        listItems.add(tem);         
        Log.e("Ninja Archives", tem.username);

    }
    // This is the array adapter, it takes the context of the activity as a first // parameter, the type of list view as a second parameter and your array as a third parameter
    ArrayAdapter<Template> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Template>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listItems);
    lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter); 

}
```

The problem is, instead of filling my listview with nice username and email strings, it's filling up with items like this:

com.android.ninjaarchives.
Template@40585690

I think somewhere along the line I have become lost, but I've been trying all sorts for ages now and getting nowhere. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks for any help.

Note: not really sure what's going on with the code; it doesn't appear to be pasting correctly.

Comment: you are adding template objects and not strings..i wld say use Custom adapter

Comment: You need to get the strings like tem.username and tem.email isteam of arryalist of template itself

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use below code, it can be a solution for you

```
public void JsonToArrayList(JSONArray myJsonArray) throws JSONException
{
    ArrayList<Template> listItems = new ArrayList<Template>();
    JSONObject jo = new JSONObject();
    Template tem = new Template();
    ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    String listItemString[] = new String[myJsonArray.length];

    for(int i = 0; i<myJsonArray.length(); i++)
    {
        jo = myJsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
        tem.username = jo.getString("username");
        tem.email = jo.getString("user_email");
       listItemString[i]  = tem.username +" - " + tem.email; // u can change it according to ur need.
        listItems.add(tem);         
        Log.e("Ninja Archives", tem.username);

    }
    // This is the array adapter, it takes the context of the activity as a first // parameter, the type of list view as a second parameter and your array as a third parameter
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listItemString);
    lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter); 

}
```

But better to write Custom adapter by extending BaseAdapter, and do listItem handling in getView method [here is one simple tutorial](http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429)

Comment: Excellent solution; I totally get it now. Thanks very much.

Comment: It is just a temporary solutions. U need to mention both the list and String[] to track click items etc.

Answer (score 1):

Take a class extending Base

```
    private class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    public CustomAdapter(Context context)
    {
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    public int getCount()
    {
        return listItems.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position)
    {
        return listItems.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView,ViewGroup parent)
    {
        //if(convertView==null)
        //convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listlayout, parent, false);
        Template data = (Template) getItem(position);
        TextView v=new TextView(context);
        v.setText(data.name);
        return v;
    }
}
```

and set adapter to your listview

```
lv.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(this));
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case you have to use a custom adapter (that extends from ArrayAdapter) and override the getView method to display in a custom layout the username and the email.